# Fetch Specific Number of Random Rows from CoreData

Tags: iphone, xcode, core-data, predicate, fetch

I'm using the code below to Fetch a queried set of all rows using CoreData matching the search criteria: itemType = 1.
But what I need to do is to Fetch a specific number of Random rows from the data instead.
For example, instead of retrieving all 100 rows of data in which the column name dataType = 1, I need to get 25 rows randomly in which dataType = 1.
I'm hoping there is relatively painless solution.
Any help is appreciated.
lq

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"MyAppName" 
                    inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]]];

NSError *error = nil;                                           
NSPredicate *predicate;
NSArray *fetchResults;
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(itemType = %i)", 1];            
[request setPredicate:predicate];
fetchResults = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

if (!fetchResults) {
        // NSLog(@"no fetch results error %@", error);
}

self.mutableArrayName = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:fetchResults];
[request release];
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not actually fetch random rows. A reasonable randomization strategy may be to fetch all of the objects matching your predicate, and then randomly select a specific number of objects.

Anyway you can use the following methods of `NSFetchRequest`:

```
- (void)setFetchLimit:(NSUInteger)limit
- (void)setFetchOffset:(NSUInteger)limit
```

Basically, `setFetchLimit` allows you to define how many rows you want to fetch (in your case you will set limit to 25), while `setFetchOffset` defines the offset at which rows will begin being returned (see the documentation of the `fetchOffset` property for details).

This is not a random process, but you may randomly generate the offset. However, it is worth noting here that, depending on the offset, you may then fetch a number of objects falling between zero and your fetch limit.

Answer (score -3):

You could also use reference approach. When you sort by view counts.
I posted long time ago about it: http://www.alterplay.com/ios-dev-tips/2010/06/fetch-random-record-with-coredata.html
Sorry for formatting. it's broken after switching from Blogger to Wordpress.

Comment: Couldn't you fix the post or else take it down?